# Browsing/Downloading S3 with BOTO and IAM

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

Following AWS IAM examples, I have the conf as below.
But this results in an "Access denied" when I use the credentials of the user with this
IAM policy attached.

Removing the Stringlike condition works fine.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "s3:prefix": "STRING/*"
    }
  }
}
]}


conn = S3Connection( key, secret );
buck = conn.get_bucket( BUCKET ); 
for key in buck.list( prefix = STRING ):
  print key.name
```

Also, in order to get an object from a bucket "subfolder",

...
   "Action":"s3:GetObject"
   ...
   "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/STRING/*"
   ...

only this restricted getObject permission is not enough (denied again), whereas it works if I add the ListBucket policy to the whole bucket. Do AWS work as in *nix when you need the READ(list) bit set on a directory in order to ACCESS(read) a 777 file contained in the same directory?

Can you please help? I am not sure about my understanding of IAM policies.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed removing get_bucket(), which probably requires more permissions (ListAllMyBuckets?)

```
conn = S3Connection( key, secret );
mBucket = Bucket( conn, bucket );
for key in mBucket.list( prefix = prefix ):
  print key.name
return
```